# How do I "slow down" executing of tests in scala (transcation doesn't close in AfterExample)?

Tags: scala, junit, transactions, specs2

After upgrading specs/specs2 to the newest specs2 stable version I found out really weird issue in my scala tests. In my "main" class (all of my test classes extend this one) I have `before` and `after`

```
abstract class BaseSpec2 extends SpecificationWithJUnit with BeforeExample with AfterExample {

  def before = startSqlTransaction
  def after = rollbackSqlTransaction

[...]
}
```

`before` starts transaction and `after` ends it (I dont think I have to put code to show you how it works, If I am wrong please let me know).

I'm using JUnit in Eclipse to execute my tests in scala.

When I'm running them I get SqlError in some of them (the result of tests are not stable, what I mean is sometimes it ends up with success for one test, sometimes when this test won't go without error another will):

> Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

I think this error shows up, because `before` starts transaction before every tests but `after` does not close it for some reason. I debugged `rollbackSqlTransaction` and `startSqlTransaction` and it showed me that: 
- When I start e.g 5 tests, transaction opens 5 times but closes only one time.

When I have added empty `step` beetwen those 5 tests everythink worked fine.

When I have more than 5 tests it goes even more weird, e.g transaction starts 4 times then it closes then starts then closes etc. With 40 tests it opened 40 times and closed 29 times (its not stable too).

In my opinion for some reason tests are running so fast that executer is not able to close transaction, but I might be wrong. Is there anythink I can put in my code to slow them down? Or am I wrong and doing somethink else wrong? 
Also when I'm running my tests it seems like few of those tests are starting at the same time (they arent going one by one), but it might be just an ilusion in eclipse.
Thanks for an answer and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you using a "shared" transaction? In that case you might be seeing the effects of examples being executed concurrently. You can fix that by adding `sequential` to your specification.

Comment: If by "shared" you mean that I want to use one transaction for few tests, youre wrong, but like i said I think for some reason `after` was not closing transaction after each test so they were probably sharing transaction (or I'm wrong about it and meaby newest specs2 trigger concurent execute). That said, `sequential` helpt me cause now it works like it should (now they are goin one by one and that fixed issue probably). Thanks! ;)

Comment: Good to know that it's working now. I added an "official" answer so that you can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that transactions are not being closed properly because examples are being executed concurrently. Just add `sequential` at the beginning of your specification and things should be fine.